# Android 10 - can't search Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, search, bluetooth

I am using a Galaxy note 10+ and I am testing Bluetooth functionality with app I've programmed.
When android version of the phone was 9, Bluetooth operations 
                          ( searching, paring, connecting and so on )
were working but since upgrading version to android 10 a month ago,
my app is unable to find nearby Bluetooth devices.

In android OS menu, Bluetooth search is working.
My app was able to search Bluetooth devices on android 9 but not on android 10.
What's wrong with android 10 ?
How can I solve the problem that app is unable to search Bluetooth devices on Android 10 ?
Please help me.

Comment: Maybe someone can help you if you share some code you have written for android 9.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue.
I was using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION but it didn't worked on my new android 10.
Using ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION makes it work as expected.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this,
        arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ),
        PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH
)
```

Answer (score -1):

in android 10 need permission

BLUETOOTH

BLUETOOTH_ADMIN

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION    // if your app run on background

and **device location** must be **turn on**   and you have to check is device location is on

LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

```
if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
```

startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

```
}
```